# Does the Fallout 4 1.03 patch fix the glitches related to infinite building?

Tags: fallout-4, ps4, xbox-one

Can someone who has installed the 1.03 patch on console (PS4/Xbox One) verify this?

Specifically, there are two glitches that are necessary for building without limits:

1. Unlimited resources
   This is done by emptying out a workshop and having only shipments in your inventory (at least 5). Then store all junk' and quickly 'take all' before the shipments turn into their raw materials. You may or may not be asked to confirm the take all so be ready to quickly confirm.
2. Unlimited build size
   Drop a bunch of weapons and then enter workshop mode. Simply highlight a weapon and select 'store'. Lather, rinse, repeat and your build limit will gradually go down.

Basically if I can't do these glitches anymore then I know to avoid the patch.

**I have read the release notes and they don't reference these glitches at all.** At the same time, it doesn't mean the issues weren't patched. I am a software developer with public facing products myself and am very aware that sometimes a company doesn't disclose everything or changes get lost in translation.

That's why I'm looking for actual proof of someone that has installed the version 1.03 and can still do the glitches. I took time to write instructions for the glitches so someone could give it a try.

Comment: you mean, aside from the developer console? (Most variables are editable through the console, hence why you can spawn people, enemies, and weapons in the heat of battle)

Comment: Sorry, when I said "console", I meant ps4 and Xbox I have clarified the question to note this and added the appropriate tags.

Comment: Also, to the down voter,  I would like feedback on why this is not a valid question. How could you want to be a part of a community that doesn't want others to improve their questions? Without the feedback I will likely just leave this community and that can't be a good stack policy

Comment: @kraftydevil Comments are entirely **optional**.  Downvoters (and upvoters) don't have to leave comments when they vote, because the act of voting is more important than informing the poster of why they vote.  That feedback is meant for *all* readers, not just you.

Comment: @Frank - I'm aware that comments are optional. I'm also aware that I have an option to request feedback and improve my question for others.

Comment: You do. But if someone would comment on why they did so, they'd already have done so. Threatening to leave because you don't get that feedback that is optional isn't going to do anything but make voters even less likely to do so. This is the system. This is how it works.

Comment: Retaining members who want to provide quality questions and answers is important. I wanted the downvoter to know that their actions were causing me to feel unwelcome. A simple number like '-1' is a very high level (low detail) feedback mechanism. If I answered a question with just a number then it would certainly be deleted. The system could be improved.

Comment: The feedback isn't for you, primarily.  If you want to take it personally, we can't stop you, but that's not what it's intended for.  That's why votes are anonymous to begin with.  It's not about *you*.  It's all about **quality**.

Comment: I don't have to be the primary reason to receive feedback for it to be an intelligent thing to ask for. Questions are editable for a reason and feedback does matter. It's definitely about quality since quality people will produce quality questions and answers. The stack sites have an opportunity to improve their community. Not leaving context specific information for the OP is irresponsible. Don't worry as I'm not taking it personally as an individual. I do think the stack community as a whole should take personally any missed opportunity at improving said community.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35665/discussion-between-frank-and-kraftydevil).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I accidentally updated my game to 1.03 and the glitches still work. ****phew****

This video shows all 3 items required for acceptance in one continuos shot:

1. Proof that version 1.03 was installed: (0:00)
2. Proof that the unlimited resources glitch still works (0:15)
3. Proof that the unlimited build capacity glitch still works (0:40)

Comment: Would love to hear why this was downvoted. I actually provided proof to the OP, which was more than the speculative release notes could tell me.

Comment: This answer is linked to the meta post http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11283/answering-a-question-when-the-only-acceptable-answer-is-a-video?cb=1

Comment: @kraftydevil: Was this question merged or something? You're talking about the OP like it's someone other than you.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant "original post" in this context.

Comment: Please summarize the video content in text in your answer.

Comment: @ChaseSandmann - could you elaborate on what else you're looking for? There is a number bulleted list of what happens in the video. I added time markers in case you want to jump to certain part but it looks spelled out to me. Let me know if you are looking for something else.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the patch notes on the wiki, is does not look like these "features" were removed in this patch. The full list can be found [here.](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_patch_1.3)

Below are the workshop related fixes as listed:

- Fixed a bug that would cause settler counts to appear incorrectly
- Fixed an issue that could prevent the player from setting up a supply line in settlements with a high population
- Improvements to snapping pieces together while in Workshop mode
- Fixed an issue that caused powered items to stop functioning permanently if its power source was ever removed
- Player can now build workbenches in their Diamond City house
- Building wires no longer uses up copper
- Fixed issue with certain settlement attacks not generating properly
- Fixed an issue with settlement happiness calculations
- Settlers assigned to weapons stand will now stand next to it
- Diamond City house now shows provided power
- Repairing items will now correctly consume resources
- Fixed an issue where companion would ignore commands at workshop locations
- Fixed an issue with crops appearing destroyed after saving and reloading

Comment: I appreciate the response but it assumes that the release notes are entirely transparent. I did read the patch notes to make sure they didn't state they took it out. However, just because they don't state it doesn't mean it's not the case. I am a software developer myself and am very aware of things that get changed without publicly announcing them. Companies do it all the time so I am looking for actual proof. I will update my question to clarify this. Thanks for bringing this up as it is important.

Comment: @kraftydevil - If nobody gets around to testing it and I don't forget to, I'll try to get around to it next time I pop FO4 in. I also feel like that's a pretty "important" glitch to mention so I'd be surprised if they left something like that out (yes, as a software developer myself, I can relate). Especially considering how minor some of the others are.

Comment: Considering neither of those is really dangerous nor detrimental to gameplay I imagine they wouldn't bother patching them. Notice that all of the listed issues may appear minor but also only make things cheaper, easier, and more accurate for the player. Removing unlimited resources and building doesn't affect "normal" play and is only detrimental to players that use it.

Comment: @Reafexus - I agree. Although I'd probably say it's still on their "todo" list, although probably on the bottom.

Comment: @Reafexus - It depends how much you exploit the glitch. They didn't put limits on the building because of gameplay restrictions - they did it because of the limits of the PS4/Xbox One. By utilizing these 2 glitches, you can build until you crash the game. Crashing can occur for a number of reasons, but I'm sure the system is working much harder when trying to display a settlement of a very large size. For example, these settlements crash often: https://youtu.be/rES0OpFz4So and https://youtu.be/DPbUly-1ujQ

Comment: @DangerZone - turns out I found out for sure by accidentally switching the internet on with auto-update. Again, my apologies for not originally including in my OP the fact that I had read the release notes and my reasons for paranoia about software patches.

Answer (score 1):

i did the unlimited resources glitch just now, and it worked the first time (however i only got it up to 450 copper) then i did it at a different settlement, 250 copper, then I've just done it at starlight drive through and was unable to get it to work....

Hmmmm

Edit: I reloaded twice, attempted it again, and was able to get it back up to 100, before it occurred again, i do believe that you can still do it, its just a matter of speed still? but i could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

I've used the settlement size trick since the patch (today even). I didn't even know about the other trick and can't comment on it.